# How do I get a view object after using bindview?

Tags: android, view, cursor, adapter, loader

I have a custom cursor adapter with a loader.  I want to get the view object in onLoadFinished() after it loads the data and creates the view with bindview so I can change the EditText view's properties (i.g. visibility).  But bindview does not return a reference to the view object.

Can I just use..

```
TextView myView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.recipe_instructions);
```

in

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    dataAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    dataAdapter.bindView(findViewById(R.id.recipe_name), this, cursor);
    dataAdapter.bindView(findViewById(R.id.recipe_instructions), this, cursor);

    TextView myView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.recipe_instructions);
}
```

In this case I'm just creating 1 view for each id but what if I created many?  How would I get a reference to the view objects so I could change the properties of just 1 in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your cursor adapter must be like :

```
public class TodoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
  public TodoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  super(context, cursor, 0);
  }
// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it, 
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point. 
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
}
// The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
// such as setting the text on a TextView. 
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  // Find fields to populate in inflated template
  TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);
  TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority);
  // Extract properties from cursor
  String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
  int priority = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("priority"));
  // Populate fields with extracted properties
  tvBody.setText(body);
  tvPriority.setText(String.valueOf(priority));
}
}
```

use this link : [Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)